# Счетчик времени JS как добавить нули, когда цифры меньше десяти?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как добавить нули в следующий код, код числа меньше 10?

```
let spendTime = document.getElementById("spendTime");
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;
let timer;

function updateSeconds() {
seconds += 1;
 if (seconds > 59) {
seconds = 0;
minutes +=1
}

if (minutes >59) {
minutes = 0 ;
hours +=1;
}

spendTime.innerHTML = `${hours} : ${minutes} : ${seconds}`;
}

timer = setInterval(updateSeconds, 1000);
```

Comment: вообще, не принято отвечать на такие вопросы, но добавьте `if(seconds < 10) seconds  = '0'+seconds;` и `if(minutes < 10) minutes = '0'+minutes;` после `if(...){...}` соответственно

Comment: а, ну и, возможно, вам придется преобразовывать строчные значений секунды и минуты в число после такой манипуляции. но это уже как-нибудь попробуйте загуглить, это не сложно) хотя, можно создать отдельную переменную для вывода строчного значения, ну, в общем, это уже другая история

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для добавления ведущих нулей, используйте метод [padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) :

```js
let spendTime = document.getElementById("spendTime");
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;
let timer;

function updateSeconds() {
  seconds += 1;
  if (seconds > 59) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes += 1
  }

  if (minutes > 59) {
    minutes = 0;
    hours += 1;
  }

  spendTime.innerHTML = `${hours} : ${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')} : ${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
}

timer = setInterval(updateSeconds, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="spendTime"></div>
```

Comment: Всем, спасибо! padStart крутой метод!!!

Comment: padStart не работает в IE

Comment: @Лунатик: есть ещё и `padEnd()`, чтобы добавлять нужное количество в конец строки.

Comment: @SanyaH: я Вам больше скажу - IE даже сам Microsoft не поддерживает уже.

Comment: @UModeL если бы у заказчиков была такая же позиция как и у Вас :-)

Comment: @SanyaH: двойную цену таким заказчикам ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Можете написать функцию, в которой добавлять "0", а потом возвращать обрезанный результат. А можете и так, как в примере

```js
let spendTime = document.getElementById("spendTime");
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;
let timer;

//Добавляем метод обекту Number
Number.prototype.toLeadZeroString = function (count) {
  const preZero = '0'.repeat(count-1);
  return this ? (preZero + this).slice(-count) : this
}

function updateSeconds() {
  seconds += 1;
  if (seconds > 59) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes +=1
  }

  if (minutes >59) {
    minutes = 0 ;
    hours +=1;
  }

  spendTime.innerHTML = `${hours.toLeadZeroString(2)} : ${minutes.toLeadZeroString(2)} : ${seconds.toLeadZeroString(2)}`;
}

timer = setInterval(updateSeconds, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="spendTime"></div>
```